# Understanding alpha blending operation

Tags: image-processing, alphablending

This question is regarding a clarification I needed in the accepted answer pertaining to the right way of implementing alpha-blending(link provided here):
[How to do alpha compositing with a list of RGBA data in numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398939/how-to-do-alpha-compositing-with-a-list-of-rgba-data-in-numpy-arrays)

In the step where the output image's RGB values are populated, there is a division by the precalculated output alpha values(relevant snippet pasted below)

```
# Work out resultant RGB
outRGB = (srcRGB*srcA[...,np.newaxis] + dstRGB*dstA[...,np.newaxis]*(1-srcA[...,np.newaxis])) / outA[...,np.newaxis]
```

I wanted to understand why that is done. Is not just multiplying by srcA and dstA, as is done in the numerator, sufficient? The extra division seems to change the factor for the blending operation.
As an example, if srcA is 0.5 and dstA is also 0.5, there should be an equal contribution of 50% from both images. However, with the above, the src gets a weightage of 2/3 whereas dst gets 1/3.

P.S: Asking as a separate question here instead of a comment there since I'm new and do not have enough reputation points to post a question there.

Comment: It's following the equations in the page linked at the top of the question: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Alpha_compositing#/Alpha_blending

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo . Actually, I did go through that page too. Though the math of it eludes me, the general idea I got is that this compositing expression favors and achieves a higher weightage for foreground as an indicator of lower depth. But I am curious still as to why the direct usage of the alpha values is not sufficient. Aren't they directly indicating desired levels of transparency already? 
I will look further to understand the derivation of it, but if you have any simple/intuitive reference on this, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When blending the resulting `outRGB` with the background, using `outA` as alpha, one will multiply `outRGB` by `outA`. That is why we need to divide by `outA`.

Think of blending first B with the background, and then A on top (using A and B because it's more logical than `src` and `dst` in the linked code; the [linked page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Alpha_compositing#/Alpha_blending) also uses A and B). Let's call the background X, and Y is the result of mixing B on X. `alpha_A` is the alpha for color A, etc.:

```
Y = B * alpha_B + X * (1-alpha_B)
out = A * alpha_A + Y * (1-alpha_A)
    = A * alpha_A + (B * alpha_B + X * (1-alpha_B)) * (1-alpha_A)
    = A * alpha_A + B * alpha_B * (1-alpha_A) + X * (1-alpha_B) * (1-alpha_A)
    = A * alpha_A + B * alpha_B * (1-alpha_A) + X * (1 - (alpha_A + alphaB * (1-alpha_A)))
```

If we now separate `out` from the background again (let's call it color C), we must have:

```
out = C * alpha_C + X * (1-alpha_C)
```

So comparing the two equations:

```
out = A * alpha_A + B * alpha_B * (1-alpha_A) + X * (1 - (alpha_A + alphaB * (1-alpha_A)))
out = C * alpha_C + X * (1-alpha_C)
```

we must have:

```
alpha_C = alpha_A + alphaB * (1-alpha_A)
C * alpha_C = A * alpha_A + B * alpha_B * (1-alpha_A)
```

This latter one can be rewritten as:

```
C = (A * alpha_A + B * alpha_B * (1-alpha_A)) / alpha_C
```

Comment: This is great! Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks @CrisLuengo

Comment: This is a pretty good explanation of how the formula is derived. Thanks